# Align labelText of TextField when focused

Tags: flutter, textfield

The labelText property
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/labelText.html
is moved upwards when the textfield is focused and you have an Inputdecoration like this:

```
InputDecoration(
  labelText: labelText,
  filled: true,
  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: const BorderSide(
      color: ImpexColors.grey,
      width: 1.0,
    ),
  ),
  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: const BorderSide(
      color: ImpexColors.secondaryColor,
      width: 2.0,
    ),
  ),
  labelStyle: TextStyle(
    color: ImpexColors.blue,
  ),
)
```

It is then aligned within the middle of the upper border.
Is there a possibility to change the position of the labelText, when the TextField is focused?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, kida?

```
  FocusNode myFocusNode = FocusNode();
  ...
  TextFormField(
      focusNode: myFocusNode,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
          height: myFocusNode.hasFocus ? 0.1 : 1, // 0,1 - label will sit on top of border
        ),
        labelText: labelText,
  ...
      ));
```

would also have to add:

```
onTap: () =>  setState(() {FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(myFocusNode);})
```